# Excel VBA: Automated Excel Backup Stopped Working due to "Compile Error: Cannot find file or library"

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, backup, vba

I have an inventory xls file, that includes a diagram of the office.  When the xls is opened, the VBA automatically makes a backup of the file before any changes are made.  That has worked for the past year.  Today it has broken.

Yesterday, the file was working fine.
1)  I added some info to the xls sheet - nothing unusual; the same sort of info I've added over the past year.   I did NOT edit the VBA. 
2)  I added some objects (shapes-circle, square, etc) to the tab with the office diagram.

Today, the file is not working.
1)  The VBA debugger gives an error on open:  "Compile Error:  Cannot find file or library."
2)  Numerous text boxes/shapes have vanished off the tab with the diagram. I did not remove them.

UPDATE 1:  I moved a shape on the diagram, and all the text boxes reappeared.

Any suggestions to fix this are appreciated.

```
'Saves an exact copy of the file upon opening it to the \Back_Tracker location and added today's date to the filename.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WBPath As String, WBName As String, TimeStampStr As String, PassW As String

WBPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
WBName = ThisWorkbook.Name
'PassW = "something"

Const cstrBACKUP As String = "Backup_Tracker"

If InStr(1, WBPath, cstrBACKUP) = 0 Then        'prevent backups from making backups of themselves.

    TimeStampStr = Format(Now(), "YYYY-MM-DD_hh-mm_")

     'Application.StatusBar = "Saving backup..."
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=WBPath & Application.PathSeparator & cstrBACKUP & Application.PathSeparator & TimeStampStr & WBName
     'Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
     'Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Excel VBA is that the code can sometimes corrupt when opening.  It used to be the case with Access as well, but I'm not sure if that was eventually fixed.

My solution was to either make backup copies after each edit, or use source control for the Excel file.  Its the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.  [image: Missing reference]

Unchecked this, and it's working now.

[Reference](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/09288f15-72a0-4410-84be-cfb5e87908b6/excel-2010-macro-compile-error-cant-find-project-or-library?forum=officesetupdeployprevious)

1. Open the database or application.
2. Open a module in Design view or press ALT+F11 to switch to the Visual Basic Editor.
3. On the Tools menu, click References.
4. Clear the check box for the type library or object library marked as "Missing:"